# How Would You Explain "One's Work Protecting...." Grammatically?

Tags: participles

I do not feel comfortable with such constructs that contain "one's work ...ing" as the following:

- "[University of British Columbia marine biologist Amanda Vincent has
  won the prestigious Indianapolis Prize for her work protecting
  seahorses](https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/british-columbia/ubc-seahorse-expert-awarded-1.5565937#:%7E:text=University%20of%20British%20Columbia%20marine%20biologist%20Amanda%20Vincent%20has%20won%20the%20prestigious%20Indianapolis%20Prize%20for%20her%20work%20protecting%20seahorses.)."
- "[Learn more about her work protecting the rights of women and girls](https://www.mandelawashingtonfellowship.org/program-impact-stories/fellowship-celebrates-international-womens-day-by-highlighting-womenofcourage/#:%7E:text=Learn%20more%20about%20her%20work%20protecting%20the%20rights%20of%20women%20and%20girls)."

No matter how I feel about it, there is no denying that it is done and it is fairly commonplace, so I am not going to say it is wrong. However, it does not sit well with me. How would you explain this phrase grammatically?

Is "protecting" a present participle? If so, construct wise, "her work" will have to be the subject of "protecting," but meaning wise, it is clearly wrong; the assumed subject is she.

The only explanation I can come up with is that this is an idiomatic expression. Maybe "protecting ..." is a gerund and it is an appositive to the immediately preceding "her work"?

Your input will be much appreciated!

Comment: How do you feel about "his job making widgets"?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks for the comment. That is indeed the other thing I thought about (but failed to included in my OP).

Yes, I see the question should have been better there. My apologies.

Comment: @Draconis I know such phrasing is done, but I do feel weird about it also.

Comment: @Draconis That ‘feels’ like a different construction to me, a simple reduced relative clause (‘his job, which is making widgets’).

Comment: See this similar question asked yesterday on ELL (but now closed): https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/338835/making-the-office-more-efficient

Comment: I had thought this was an appositive. i

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In "experience teaching this material over a number of years convinced me that", is "experience" a noun adjunct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/524804/in-experience-teaching-is-experience-a-noun-adjunct)