# Non-finite clause vs phrase

Tags: phrases, gerunds, infinitives, participles, nonfinite-clause-complementation

We know that a *clause* is a sentence which is a part of a sentence. So, a clause is itself *a sentence having a subject and a predicate*, but a *phrase* is just *a group of words*.
**To tell you the truth**,I was terrified.
He regrets now **having jumped**.
I apologized **for being late**.
Nowadays Infinitives, participles and gerunds are regarded as '*non-finite clauses*'.

My question is : -
(1) Are all the three parts (written above in bold letters) **phrases as well as (non-finite) clauses** at the same time? 
(2) Why are they regarded as clauses **though they are not a complete sentence** having a subject and a predicate? 
(3) Is there **no distinction between a phrase and a (non-finite) clause** in this case?

Comment: Not in grammatical terms. A clause is not necessarily a sentence. It might be, but it can also be just part of a sentence. Your examples are clauses that (like most non-finite clauses) have no overt subject, but have a predicate consisting of a verb phrase.

Comment: @BillJ, can those non-finite clauses be called phrases as well? What is the distinction between a phrase and a non-finite clause?

Comment: The important thing is that unlike phrases they have a subject-predicate structure, and hence qualify as clauses. The fact that, like most non-finite clauses, they don't have overt subjects doesn't matter because they (usually) have _understood_ subjects.

Comment: @BillJ, you are saying clauses can be just a part of a sentence. But parts of speech, phrases -- these are also parts of a sentence? How can you differentiate between a phrase and a clause? This is the key point of my question.

Comment: I've just answered that question.

Comment: But  the above-mentioned non-finite clauses don't have a subject-predicate structure. How canthey qualify as clauses ??

Comment: As I said, non-finite clauses usually have _understood_ subjects rather than overt ones. The predicate, however, is overt, consisting of a verb phrase, e.g. "having jumped" in one of your examples.

Comment: They are phrases too. At least according to how [this book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cambridge_Grammar_of_the_English_Language) defines phrases.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/555449).

Answer (score -1):

To tell you the truth--> infintive phrase
He regrets now having jumped--> "having" --> gerund phrase
I apologized for being late--> "being late" gerund phrase . "Being late" is the object of the preposition "for"

All of the above are PHRASES , which are nonfinite,  because they may be either without a subject ( subjectless ) or have the subject with accusative case  , and NOT clauses .

Phrases and clauses are different constrcutions . Phrases have either a subject or a verb , never both . Clauses have a subject and a tensed verb , and may have complete or incomplete meaning ( independent or dependent ) .

A "nonfinite clause" would something like :

I never saw "him eat salad" --> "him" is the subject in accusative case , and "eat" is the nonfinite verb .

Hope it helps .